# How to reverse XML data tags using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, reverse

For example, below XML file.

```
<person>
    <name>John</name>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Diane</name>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>Chris</name>
    <id>3</id>
</person>
```

Now,
In XSLT, If I code:

```
<xsl:template match="person">
 <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

So, In HTML file It will display John1Diane2Chris3.

But,
I need following output:
**Diane2John1Chris3**

I need to reverse order of first 2 data tags.
Here below first 2 tags

```
<name>John</name>
<id>1</id>

<name>Diane</name>
<id>2</id>
```

Any Idea folks ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very specific solution to a very specific problem:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="person">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="name[text()='Diane']|id[text()='2']" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="name[not(text()='Diane')] |
                                       id[not(text()='2')]" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
Diane2John1Chris3
```

A more general solution would require a more general description of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:template match="person">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="name[2]|id[2]"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="name[position() != 2]|id[position() != 2]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

This assumes there is always a `name` and `id` pair. If that's not the case, solution will be more complex.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will allow you to control how much of first tags you want to reverse but I tend to agree with lwburk that it might be overkill if you know for sure that all you need is just to inverse only two first tags.

```
<xsl:template match="person">
         <xsl:for-each select="name[position() &lt; 3]">
             <xsl:sort select="position()" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="./following-sibling::id[position() = 1]"/>
         </xsl:for-each>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="name[position() = 2]/following-sibling::*[position() &gt; 1]"/>
</xsl:template>
```